# Проблемы с импортом модуля livewires в python3

Tags: python-3.5

Установил pygame и livewires, при попытке написания простейшего элемента столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
from livewires import games

games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)

games.screen.mainloop()
```

при запуске интерпритатор выдает следующее:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File “/home/flex/Python/Panic at the pizzeria/main.py”, line 1, in
>
> from livewires import games
>
> File “”, line 969, in _find_and_load
>
> File “”, line 958, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File “”, line 664, in _load_unlocked
>
> File “”, line 634, in
>   _load_backward_compatible
>
> File
>   “/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/LiveWires-2.1-py3.5.egg/livewires/**init**.py”,
>   line 32, in
>
> File “”, line 969, in _find_and_load
>
> File “”, line 958, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File “”, line 664, in _load_unlocked
>
> File “”, line 634, in
>   _load_backward_compatible
>
> File
>   “/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/LiveWires-2.1-py3.5.egg/livewires/beginners.py”,
>   line 798, in
>
> AttributeError: module ‘tkinter’ has no attribute ‘tkinter’

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему?